# Reading a JSON file with fsPromises returns node:internal/process/promises:279 error

Tags: node.js, json

so I was making a program that scrapes a website and stores the data in json format with fsPromises.writeFile and another program that reads the json file with fsPromises.readFile. the json file is written correctly as I've checked it manually but when I try to read it with fsPromises it returns the error mentioned below.

I've checked the file path and it's all correct, and I can literally see the json file in the directory and when I use require to parse the JSON file it works, but I want to use fs to check is the file is present and to parse from the file

I wrote the JSON file with fsPromises like this

```
await fsPromises.writeFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "json", "productVarables.json"),
      JSON.stringify(variables),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error while writing the JSON" + err);
        } else {
          console.log("successfuly written the JSON file");
        }
      }
    );
```

and when I try to read it using fsPromises like this

```
await fsPromises.readFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "json", "productVarables.json"),
      "utf-8",
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }
    );
```

I get the following error

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\desktop\Project\Node\Scraper\json\productVariables.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\desktop\\Project\\Node\\Scraper\\json\\productVariables.json'
}
```

Comment: Your code says `productVarables.json` (incorrect spelling of "variables"), the error says `productVariables.json`. Also, why use callbacks when you're using promises?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked after I corrected the name and removed the callback function. I just starting using node only recently, hence the mistake of using callbacks with promises, a mistake painfully learned. Thank you